# For $A_1 A_2\cdots A_{11}$ a regular $11$-gon with circumradius $2$, and point $P$ at distance $3$ from the center, find $\sum PA_k^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Let $A_1 A_2 \dotsb A_{11}$ be a regular $11$-gon inscribed in a circle of radius $2$. Let $P$ be a point, such that the distance from $P$ to the center of the circle is $3$. Find
> $$PA_1^2 + PA_2^2 + \dots + PA_{11}^2$$

This kind of reminded me of roots of unity, because of a regular polygon inscribed in a circle, but I'm not sure on how to work this problem.

Comment: I would start with a 2-gon, $A_1$ and $A_2$ diametrically opposite but everything else the same. Then maybe a 3-gon (equilateral triangle) and a 4-gon (square). If things are not clear by that point...

Comment: That works, very nicely. Use the  roots of unity.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions of the equation $z^n=1$ for positive values of the integer $n$ are the $n^{th}$ roots of unity. In polar form, the equation $z=1$ can be written as $$z=\cos2k\pi+i\sin2k\pi=e^{2ik\pi}$$ where $k=0,1,2,\dots$

Using de Moivre's formula we can find $$z^{\frac{1}{n}}=(\cos2k\pi+i\sin2k\pi)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(e^{2ik\pi})^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ $$=(\cos{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}+i\sin{\frac{2k\pi}{n}})=e^{2i{\frac{k}{n}}\pi}$$ where $k=0,1,2,\dots,(n-1)$

If we write $$\alpha_k=e^{2i{\frac{k\pi}{n}}}=\cos{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}+i\sin{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$$ where $k=0,1,2,\dots,(n-1)$

Then all the the $n^{th}$ roots of unity we get with the values of $k=0,1,2,\dots,(n-1)$ are $$=1,e^{\frac{i2\pi}{n}},e^{\frac{i4\pi}{n}},e^{\frac{i6\pi}{n}},\dots,e^{\frac{i2(n-1)\pi}{n}}$$ $$=1,\alpha,\alpha^{2},\alpha^{3},\dots,\alpha^{n-1}$$ where $\alpha=e^{\frac{i2\pi}{n}}$

If we find $\alpha_{n-1}$ then we get $\alpha_{n-1}=e^{\frac{-i2\pi}{n}}$ so one can similarly show that $\alpha_{n-2}=e^{\frac{-i4\pi}{n}}$ and in general $$\alpha_{n-k}=e^{-2i\frac{k\pi}{n}}=\cos{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}-i\sin{\frac {2k\pi}{n}}$$

From here we can see that $$\alpha_0=\overline{\alpha_n},\alpha_2=\overline{\alpha_{n-2}},\alpha_3=\overline{\alpha_{n-3}},\dots,\alpha_k=\overline{\alpha_{n-k}}$$

And conversely $$\alpha_{n-k}=\overline{\alpha_{k}}$$

Geometrically the $n$ roots represent the $n$ vertices of a regular polygon of $n$ sides. The $n$-sided polygon is inscribed by a circle of radius $|z|=r=1$ with the center at the origin of the polygon.

$\hskip2in$
[image]

Let the center of circle $P$ be origin, i.e. $P\equiv(0,0)$ so according to question we can generalised the result as $A_k=3+2e^{i\tfrac{2\pi k}{11}}$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots,10$ in which all the $11$ points are equally spaced on the circle of radius $2$ centered at $3$. So we can get the distance for any point $k$ as $$PA_k^2=|3+2e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{11}}|^2=\left(3+2e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{11}}\right)\left(3+2e^{-i\frac{2\pi k}{11}}\right)$$ $$=13+6\left(e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{11}}+e^{-i\frac{2\pi k}{11}}\right)$$

Also, $$\sum_{i=0}^{10}PA_k^2=PA_1^2+PA_2^2+\dots+PA_{11}^2=\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(13+6\left(e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{11}}+e^{-i\frac{2\pi k}{11}}\right)\right)$$

Using $\cos\theta=\frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}$ $$=\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(13+6\left(2\cos{\frac{2\pi k}{11}}\right)\right)$$ $$=13\cdot11+12\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(\cos{\frac{2\pi k}{11}}\right)$$

Using the property Sum of the $N^{th}$ Roots of Unity is $0$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}=0$$

Equating to $0$ separately the real and the imaginary parts, we obtains two well known trigonometric identities as $$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\cos{\frac{2\pi ik}{N}}=0$$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sin{\frac{2\pi ik}{N}}=0$$

We can also use cosine summation formula to evaluate the value of $\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(\cos{\frac{2\pi k}{11}}\right)$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\cos{(ak)}=\csc{\left({\frac{a}{2}}\right)}\sin{\left({{\frac{1}{2}}a(n+1)}\right)}\cos{\left({\frac{an}{2}}\right)}$$

Putting the value of of $\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(\cos{\frac{2\pi k}{11}}\right)$ in above equation we get
$$\implies PA_k^2=PA_1^2+PA_2^2+\dots+PA_{11}^2=13\cdot11+12\cdot0$$ $$=143$$

$$\therefore PA_k^2=PA_1^2+PA_2^2+\dots+PA_{11}^2=143$$

Comment: If you note that a question is a duplicate of another which you have already answered, please do not copy your answer to the new question. Rather, please let the OP know you have answered their question in another post by, for example, providing a link to it in the comments. I have deleted your duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of using the roots of unity.

$z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_{11}$ are the vertices of our 11=gon.

$z_n = 2e^{(\frac {2n\pi}{11} + \alpha)i}$

$\alpha$ would represent a factor for the rotation of the 11-gon.  We will see if it turns out to be relevant.

$P = 3$

$|(3-z_1)|^2 + |(3-z_2)|^2 +\cdots +  |(3-z_{11})|^2\\
(3-z_1)(3-\bar z_1) + (3-z_2)(3-\bar z_2) +\cdots +  (3-z_{11})(3-z_{11})$

$(3-z_1)(3-\bar z_1) = 9 - 3 z_1 - 3\bar{z_1} + z_1\bar z_1$

$z_n\bar z_n = |z_n|^2 = 4$

$(3-z_1)(3-\bar z_1) + (3-z_2)(3-\bar z_2) +\cdots +  (3-z_{11})(3-z_{11}) = 13\cdot 11 - 3\sum_\limits{n=1}^{11}z_n - 3\sum_\limits{n=1}^{11}\bar z_n $

Since we have a regular polygon centered at the origin...

$3\sum_\limits{n=1}^{11}z_n = 0$ and $3\sum_\limits{n=1}^{11}\bar z_n = 0$

$\alpha$ turns out to not be relevant.

$13\cdot 11 = 143$